# Live entity framework connection string on remote server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, connection-string

I have an application that uses entity framework. I created my model with a connection to a database I stood up on my development machine. I am now moving the application to our development environment and standing it up in IIS.

I changed the connection string to point at the remote server, recompiled and oushed the code to the remote server, ran the app as the service account I was provided, and if providing a user that isn't in the Accounts table it gives an unknown user error (so I know it is reading from the database server on the remote server).

Where I run into a problem is when I try to make a change to the database. The service account should have read/write/execute permissions, yet [context].SaveChanges() throws an error. I am fairly new to entity framework so I am wondering, if i can read from a database should I be able to write and execute as well or does entity framework use more of a "live" connection that Is established when compiled on the server.

TL:DR application created database model on dev machine, code gets pushed to remote environment thus not allowing me to create a new model through VS. Should the application still have proper access by just changing the EF connection string and recompiling on my local evironment?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it says see inner exception. so I went one inner exception deeper and it still says see inner exception. Another developer that needs to use the database is having problems too so we may think it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission problem. The admin didn't have the database set up like DEV